# How to save cron job

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-cron

I am trying to start cron job because I get an error when trying to install the extension.

according to this guide:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

1. I opened Putty and connected to the server
2. Run commend  'crontab -e'
3. I put this line at the bottom

   ```
   * * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
   ```

and and I chose **CTRL + O**

now the program asks me how to save it, here is a screenshot, What should I do next?
[image]

---

I save cron path Ctr+X and confirm Y(yes)

Next step When I try run Cron Job via command line:
 '**cd /bin**' 
and next line

**./magento cron:run**

I get error "Premission denied".

Below screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use below cron command in command console to fix the `check cron script` Readiness check issue

```
/usr/local/bin/php -c /usr/local/lib/php.ini /<Magento installation path>bin/magento cron:run

/usr/local/bin/php -c /usr/local/lib/php.ini /<Magento installation path>
update/cron.php

/usr/local/bin/php -c /usr/local/lib/php.ini /<Magento installation path>bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

May that help.
Please make sure you have sufficient permissions of var folder.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have these files in these folders. When I run this command I get error "No such file or directory".

Comment: Please check your php path by using `which php` command and check your php.ini path using `phpinfo()` fn on Magento root directory

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 errors I can see from your screenshot.

1. Your crontab permission is broken, your changes aren't applied in crontab yet.
2. You don't have **execute** permission on `bin/magento`

#### Solutions:

Reinstall crontab to fix read-only file system issue. Execute the following command as `root` user

```
dpkg-query -S /var/spool/cron/crontabs
apt-get install --reinstall cron
```

Add execute permission for bin/magento by use the following command

```
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

However, are you sure that the line you've added to `crontab -e` use the correct webroot directory and PHP path?

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

because as the above image your magento root dir located here

```
/home/brandswearx/ftp/
```

Answer (score 0):

I used these commands but still something blocks me.
[image]

here you have translated errors:

1448/5000
brandswearxv @ brandswearxv: ~ $ dpkg-query -S / var / spool / cron / crontabs
dpkg-query: error: can not open to read the file "/var / lib / dpkg / status" containing information about the package: Permission denied
brandswearxv @ brandswearxv: ~ $ apt-get install --reinstall cron
In: Can not read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ - DirectoryExists (13: Permission denie d)
In: Can not read /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ - DirectoryExists (13: Permission denied)
In: Can not read /etc/apt/sources.list - RealFileExists (13: Permission denie d)
E: Failed to open the lock file / var / lib / dpkg / lock - open (13: Permissio n denied)
E: Failed to block the administrative directory (/ var / lib / dpkg /), do you use administrator privileges?
brandswearxv @ brandswearxv: ~ $ chmod u + x bin / magento
brandswearxv brandswearxv @: ~ $